# How to prevent copying a wild pointer string

Tags: c++, string, mfc, crash

My program is crash intermittently when it tries to copy a character array which is not ended by a NULL terminator('\0').

```
class CMenuButton {
   TCHAR m_szNode[32];
   CMenuButton() {
     memset(m_szNode, '\0', sizeof(m_szNode));
   }
};
int main() {
  ....
  CString szTemp = ((CMenuButton*)pButton)->m_szNode; // sometime it crashes here
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

I suspected someone had not copied the character well ended by '\0', and it ended like:

```
            Stack
m_szNode    $%#^&!&!&!*@*#&!(*@(!*@@&#&*&@@!^&*&#(*!@*((*&*SDFKJSHDF*(&(*&(()(**
```

Can you tell me what is happening and what should i do to prevent the copying of wild pointer? Help will be very much appreciated!

I guess I'm unable to check if the character array is NULL before copying...

Comment: We need some more info, such as how pButton is created, and what happens to that pointer between its creation, and the line of code you've provided here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your real problem could be that `pButton` is a bad pointer, so check that out first.

The only way to be 100% sure that a pointer is correct, and points to a correctly sized/allocated object is to never use pointers you didn't create, and never accept/return pointers.  You would use cookies, instead, and look up your pointer in some sort of cookie -> pointer lookup (such as a hash table).  Basically, don't trust user input.

If you are more concerned with finding bugs, and less about 100% safety against things like buffer overrun attacks, etc. then you can take a less aggressive approach.  In your function signatures, where you currently take pointers to arrays, add a size parameter.  E.g.:

```
void someFunction(char* someString);
```

Becomes

```
void someFunction(char* someString, size_t size_of_buffer);
```

Also, force the termination of arrays/strings in your functions.  If you hit the end, and it isn't null-terminated, truncate it.

Make it so you can provide the size of the buffer when you call these, rather than calling strlen (or equivalent) on all your arrays before you call them.

This is similar to the approach taken by the "safe string functions" that were created by Microsoft (some of which were proposed for standardization).  Not sure if this is the perfect link, but you can google for additional links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565508(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. It's confirmed that pButton was deleted somewhere.... It's  not due to the fixed size character array.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

1. `pButton` doesn't point to a `CMenuButton` like you think it does, and the cast is causing undefined behavior.
2. The code that sets `m_szNode` is incorrect, overflowing the given size of 32 characters.

Since you haven't shown us either piece of code, it's difficult to see what's wrong. Your initialization of `m_szNode` looks OK.

Is there any reason that you didn't choose a CString for `m_szNode`?

Comment: +1 for (also) hitting the nail on the head for the real problem, rather than following the rabbit hole of the rest of the questions he asked :)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to make `m_szNode` a private member in `CMenuButton`, and explicitly `NULL`-terminate it in the mutator method.

```
class CMenuButton {
  private:
    TCHAR m_szNode[32];

  public:
    void set_szNode( TCHAR x ) {
        // set m_szNode appropriately
        m_szNode[ 31 ] = 0;
     }
};
```